# my website does not show on an iphone browser and I not know why

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, reactjs

I'm not sure why, but my website does not display on mobile safari. I added the

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

and it shows fine on my mac chrome and safari but not on my iphone or iphone simulator. and am using bootstrap 3 and reactjs, which should work fine on mobile, as far as i know. this has me pulling my hair out, so if anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

my website is at http://register.versame.com

Comment: I just checked it, it's fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your website fails to display anything on my Macbook's and simulated iPhone 5s' Safari.

I am getting the following error on both instances of Safari: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('. Expected a ':' following the property name 'render'. (main.js:94490)`.

Inspecting the code, I see that you have written:

```
var NotFound = React.createClass({
    displayName: "NotFound",
    render() {
        window.location = '/notfound';
    }
});
```

instead of:

```
var NotFound = React.createClass({
    displayName: "NotFound",
    render: function render() {
        window.location = '/notfound';
    }
});
```

Now, as for why your website was still working in Chrome, it is because Chrome supports ES6's [shorter syntax for method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) while Safari does not.

*Note: I used [this article](http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/09/22/ios-safari-web-inspector) to allow me to inspect your website on the simulated iPhone.*

Comment: you are awesome. thank you. i spent this whole time looking for the developer button on safari following the link you posted.

Comment: Safari —> Preferences —> Advanced —> Show Develop menu in menu bar.

Comment: @MatthewChung See my updated answer, it explains why your website was working in Chrome.

Comment: that is super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I Observed that It is not loading on few browsers due to an error in Main.js File of your website.

One Error was : SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '(' instead at var 
main.js:94490

Incorrect Code :

```
NotFound = React.createClass({displayName: "NotFound",
    render() {
        window.location = '/notfound';
    }
});
```